# Как грамотно сделать вывод графики в оконном приложении WinAPI?

Tags: c, winapi, графика

Поясните, пожалуйста, как грамотно сделать вывод графики в оконном приложении на Си и WinAPI?

Мне надо загружать множество картинок через LoadImage(), затем выводить их через BitBlt().
Я пробовал делать это по-разному, и получалось . Но как сделать это правильно, т. е. грамотно?
Правда ли, что самый правильный способ - загрузка LoadImage() в case WM_CREATE:, а вывод картинок - в case WM_PAINT:?
Причём case WM_PAINT: должен быть примерно таким:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 265, 175, memBit, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 22, 14, memBit2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
```

Правильно ли я понял, что весь вывод сотен картинок должен быть между BeginPaint() и EndPaint()?
А уж какие там картинки выводить - я должен исхитриться описать через if, case, вызовы функций и т. п.?

Важнейший вопрос - все выводы картинок должны быть только между BeginPaint() и EndPaint()?
Т.е. если внутри кода возникла необходимость вывести картинку, то код должен послать сообщение WM_PAINT?

Comment: Если знаете способы лучше - поделитесь, пожалуйста. А то,что есть другие способы, я написал в изначальном сообщении.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> весь вывод сотен картинок должен быть между BeginPaint() и EndPaint()?

Если картинок много, и при этом есть нагрузка на `WM_PAINT` (видны подвисания `GUI`), то лучше вынести и эту работу из `WM_PAINT`

**Например**: генерировать дополнительный растр на текущее окно и отрисовывать в этот растр все эти сотни картинок в отдельном потоке, а на `WM_PAINT` (между `Begin/EndPaint`) - просто отрисовывать этот растр одним махом, если он готов. Это снимет нагрузку с `WM_PAINT` (с цикла обработки сообщений) и предотвратит подвисания `GUI`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы мыслите в правильном ключе. Очень грамотно делать в обработчиках сообщений то что от них ожидается. И прежде всего потому, что другие программисты, которые будут поддерживать ваш код после вас, будут ожидать именно такой организации программы. Они вам будут очень благодарны за то, что стандартные действия выполняются стандартно. И наоборот, нестандартное поведение должно быть обосновано и задокументировано.

Если говорить об отрисовке, то я бы порекомендовал вам поизучать как она организовывается в игровых проектах. Уж в играх об это сломано немало копий и в целом сформировались базовые решения под основные задачи. И еще порекомендовал бы поизучать шаблон проектирования [Модель-Вид-Контролер (MVC)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller).

Основные идеи следующие:

1. Удобно непосредственно отрисовку выполнять из единого места, так как во-первых это логично, а во-вторых легче находить ошибки отрисовки: всевозможные артефакты, наложения и прочее. Если отрисовка выполняется из разных мест, то получается ад.
2. Отделять отрисовку и расчеты это правильно. К моменту когда необходимо выполнять отрисовку у вас уже все должно быть готово, то есть позиции, цвета и прочее всех элементов должны быть уже известны. В обработчике `WM_PAINT` вы просто используете готовые данные и никаких тяжелых операций не выполняете.
3. Ключевая задача отрисовщика - определение видимости элементов в заданном прямоугольнике. Дело в том, что если у вас нет анимации, то 90% сообщений `WM_PAINT` приходят чтобы отрисвать только часть окна, причем небольшую часть. Напомню, что для определения области отрисовки служит функция [GetUpdateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144943(v=vs.85).aspx) ну и BeginPaint ее тоже возвращает. В вашем случае нужно рисовать не все сотни картинок, а только те которые попадают в область отрисовки.